# Docker variable expansion

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to do variable expansion within the ENV section of a dockerfile? In the example below I would like javaMemoryLimit to be expanded within JAVA_OPTS but I find when I run the image the java process exists as instead of having **-Xmx1024M** we are left with **-Xmx**

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-centos:latest
VOLUME /tmp
ADD myspecificcode.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV javaMemoryLimit="1024M"\
    JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:+MaxFDLimit -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx$javaMemoryLimit"
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar
```

I've got the following working but would rather it was all done via modifying the JAVA_OPTS variable rather than adding additional switches to the java command:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-centos:latest
VOLUME /tmp
ADD myspecificcode.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV javaMemoryLimit="1024M"\
    JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:+MaxFDLimit -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC"
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS  -Xmx$javaMemoryLimit -jar /app.jar
```

Comment: Did you try two separate `ENV` lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) explains that the values are only available in descendant commands. Therefore you have to split it in separate `ENV` commands:

```
ENV javaMemoryLimit=1024M \
    gcInterval=3600000
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=$gcInterval -Xmx$javaMemoryLimit"
```

> The ENV instruction sets the environment variable  to the value
>   . This value will be in the environment of all **descendant**
>   Dockerfile commands and can be replaced inline in many as well.

Comment: I reworked the file based on this feedback and now it expands as expected which is great. A problem now though is that if I define the javaMemoryLimit environment variable later in docker-compose, that it doesn't overwrite the value in the dockerfile, i.e. whatever value is set in the dockerfile does not get overwritten by the compose value for the variable.

Comment: This is expected. But you can define the variables in the same manner in the compose file to achieve the same effect as in the Dockerfile.